# Can these .htaccess mod_rewrite rules be compacted?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a few mod_rewrite rules in my htaccess files to redirect inexistent pages to a default page, like this:

- `http://domain.tld/category1/subcategoryX`
- `http://domain.tld/category1/subcategoryX/`
- `http://domain.tld/category1/subcategoryX/property1`
- `http://domain.tld/category1/subcategoryX/property1/`

all redirected to

- `http://domain.tld/category1/subcategoryX/property1/value1`

I'm doing this redirection because the subcategory and property have no page, only the values do.

These are the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^category1/[a-z-]+$             http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/property1/value1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category1/[a-z-]+/$            http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}property1/value1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category1/[a-z-]+/property1$   http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/value1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category1/[a-z-]+/property1/$  http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}value1 [R,NC,L]
```

The rules are working, but they're kinda verbose. Is there any trick to compact the rules? The difference between the first two is just the end slash, and so is for the last two.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(category1/[a-z-]+)/?$             /$1/property1/value1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(category1/[a-z-]+/property1)/?$   /$1/value1 [R,NC,L]
```

or maybe you could even redirect all url starting with category1/***

```
RewriteRule ^(category1/[a-z-]+)  /$1/property1/value1 [R,NC,L]
```